# Mongoose data wont save new instance of model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data coming in from a form, posting to `/submit`. My route looks like this:

```
var submission = require('../models/submission');

router.post('/submit', function(req,res){
    var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
    var formObjId = new ObjectId(req.body.formId);
    var data = new submission({
        formId: formObjId,
        fields: req.body.fields,
    });
    data.save(function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          //NO ERROR
        } else {
          return console.log(err);
        }
    });
    res.end("Successful submission!");
});
```

and my submissions model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Submission',{
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    formId: [],
    sourceId: [],
    fields: [],
});
```

The first part is where I'm trying to cast the string into an object id. At the save, nothing shows up as an error, although the two fields that I'm trying to save don't save with the object. The object is saved in the database with a createdAt and object id attribute. The others are blank.

Am I doing something wrong to keep the attributes from saving with the rest of the object?

Comment: Those are arrays. It would seem that your input data is not. Certainly `formId` is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your code in right way , i found following things

Your using mongoose driver this is fine.

In the schema the data type of **formId** is Array .But in the response method  the datatype which is assigning to this field  is ObjectId.

Please check once is the **fields** field is exists in request body .i.e Do you sending any field which is named as 'fields' in the post request.

These are things i found when i was first look in to the code .

I hope these may helps to you .